# Would a DeLorean actually break apart into a million pieces if hit by a freight train?

Tags: realism, back-to-the-future-part-3

The scene in *Back to the Future III* where the freight train destroys the DeLorean seems a bit unrealistic to me. It makes the car look like it was made of wood or cinder blocks. Maybe if the train was going 100 mph and the DeLorean's brakes were applied.

[image: DeLorean gets wrecked by the train]

Would it actually happen this way? Obviously the car would be heavily damaged but wouldn't it just crumple at the front and get pushed along the track?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JTVYr.png

Comment: Keep in mind that they probably wanted to minimize the damage to the $1 million+ locomotive, so the scene was no doubt shot undercranked, i.e., made to look faster on screen than it really was, so making it look realistic for a 60-80 mph collision would require explosives. Did they overdo it? Come on - would Hollywood overdo a train wreck?

Comment: What, seriously? This got migrated? ??

Comment: No @cde, that was a joke that nobody found as funny as i did :(

Answer (score 68):

Yes. A few points.

1. Real, better cars get destroyed all the time ([for instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeSs5.jpg)).
2. The DeLorean has always been known as a fairly weak car. Its construction and crash survivability is pretty low. It had a Fiberglass chassis when most cars were still fully metal. Remember in the previous movie, Marty wanted the Doc to block the tunnel with the flying DeLorean,  Doc says it would be shred to pieces by a 50s Ford metal truck.
3. The DeLorean has an unknown number of modifications, both as a time machine as well as a flying car for weight. And in the west as well. It was modified so the train could push it to 88 mph. IIRC or IMHO that probably would include ditching the now useless gas engine, again for weight.
4. Doc used parts of it to make ice. So it's missing parts.
5. Dead on the tracks, head on.  Unlike most train on car collisions, which are T bones.

#### Had it been a Ford full metal truck, no. But a Fiberglass DeLorean,  especially a questionably modified one,  sure.

Comment: When the Delorean comes out of time travel, there's always "steam" or fog around it.  It's always more of a condensation of ambient air hitting a cold object, from the looks of it.  This tells me that time travel is an endothermic process and it looks like the car comes out in a rather super-cooled state, which would also make the fiberglass you refer to more brittle, until it warms back up.

Comment: The car definitely becomes cold after time travel. Doc explicitly says so in the first movie after the initial test of the machine.

Comment: Do your research, the Delorean body is NOT fiberglass.  Ever noticed how all Deloreans are the same metallic color?  The bodywork is brushed stainless steel.  Very heavy.  Not as heavy as a 50s pickup truck, but heavy in comparison to other 80s sports cars of similar size.

Comment: @xaloroud do yours.  The stainless steel is body panels, not structural... fiberglass chassis underbody https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeLorean_DMC-12

Comment: Doc had the time machine holed up in the mine so that Marty could use it to get from 1955 to 1985. I doubt he used any significant parts of it for the ice machine.

Comment: IMO a T-bone would be more destructive than a head on collision like this. In a T-bone the car itself absorbs far more of the impact energy as opposed to be pushed. But good points, I had no idea the DeLorean's chassis was fiberglass.

Comment: @masospaghetti Remember that the crash in the film is as if the car had gone with the speed of the train straight into a solid wall... and then the ground beneath the car would have kept pushing the remains of it into that solid wall like a hellish conveyor belt. :)

Comment: @Michael Karnerfors True but the car DID crash into a barn at ~50 mph in the first movie with no damage at all. Those hay bales aren't THAT soft.

Comment: Even if the structural integrity of the car would fail utterly on impact, I find it highly unlikely that all of the parts would just fall to the track and get rolled over by the train. If they were as light and flimsy as you say, they should have gone flying off in all directions from the momentum of the train, I would expect?

Comment: Movies tend to think any car can barrel through locked gates or a barn without a scratch unless the plot calls for them to get damaged.

Comment: @KutuluMike the freight train doesn't have a cow catcher in the front. It's squared off and high off the ground. The low front of the DeLorean and the high front of the VCRY #9 would cause the debris to bounce forward and keep getting hit until a weird angle throws them sideways.

Comment: Here's a video of a 40mph crash test of a DeLorean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mjd2NTJU9g
Your image wouldn't load for me and I figured you could add this video to further demonstrate your point. 40mph against a wall destroys the car pretty effectively.

Comment: There's a higher quality version of what appears to be the same crash test @Tophandour found available:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnOGXCnTOj0

Comment: I'm sorry did you just claim there are better cars than the Delorean? I can't take the rest of the comment seriously now

Answer (score 18):

No, the car would probably not explode.

Cars get [hit by trains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IHDJRLdWQI) [all the time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWToJxKYRSc) in reality. In general, a lot of the momentum of the train goes into *moving* the car -- either pushing it along the tracks or hurling it to one side, depending on the situation.

In reality, what most likely would have happened in BTTF is the Deloran would have been hurled off to one side with a huge dent in the side. Some parts would probably have fallen off (doors, windows, etc.) but the car would likely not have disintegrated. If the car was *very precisely* placed on the tracks, it may have been thrown forward ahead of the train, and probably hit again, in which case it would be in many more pieces. But the car itself remaining in-place and falling apart is not very realistic.

Comment: The DeLorean was sitting on the tracks (road tires replaced with train wheels), head-on to the train. That would make it very hard for it to get thrown to the side, and impossible to get a dent *in the side*.

Comment: If the delorean was on the track even slightly off-center... or the train itself was even slightly off-center... then the impact would cause the car to "spin" to the side that accelerated more slowly and go flying off that way.

Comment: @KutuluMike But it was not off center, it was perfectly centered on the rail on its wheels, as was the train. A few mm or cm offset is not going to make a difference.

Comment: @Johnny in a question about realism, I think it would.... Spaceships have blown up for less than a few cm difference.

Comment: What happens to a flux capacitor loaded with depleted plutonium when hit?  I think it causes cars to blow up into pieces.  I'm going deux ex machina on this one....

Comment: "Depleted" plutonium (which isn't really a thing, but we can guess what it means by analog to depleted uranium) itself isn't going to explode, but is is *very* dense, so odds are it would survive the impact better than the rest of the car. But exposed to air it may cause other things to heat up quickly, like the fuel in the car, which might cause an explosion. But the car didn't "blow up" -- there was no fireball and the parts didn't scatter -- it just fell apart in-place.

Comment: @KutuluMike - My comment was a joke, and it wasn't supposed to make logical sense, hence what was supposed to be the "deus ex machina"  reference

Comment: @djsmiley2k - If the car were a rocket, and the train were a rocket engine, then I could see your point. In the first few milliseconds after collision, the train  is going to push its way 10's of cm (70mph=3cm/msec) into the car before the rest of the car even moves, a few cm of displacement to one side or another will make no real difference to the cars trajectory, the internal structure of the car will have a much larger effect.

Comment: Of course, the car had no fuel, causing the need to push the car. The only thing combustible would be at a guess, a lead acid battery. Minor explosion if any.

Comment: The train in the video looks rather slow. I think the train in the movie had no time to slow down.

Comment: Also, plutonium wouldn't be an issue here. This is the Mr. Fusion DeLorean.

Comment: true, so the end-result would probably be lead, which is also very dense :)

Answer (score 8):

I originally thought that this was completely possible, but after looking into how they achieved the effect, I am convinced that in real life, the DeLorean would have been crushed and would have lost a few parts, but not disintegrate to the degree that the movie DeLorean does.

This [page](http://www.backtothefuture.com/delorean/location) mentions in the "Future Facts" section that the DeLorean that you see on screen was cut up and rigged with explosives so that it would explode apart when the train hit. In fact, if you look at the [this clip](https://youtu.be/tu-cxDG2mW8?t=17s) (about 17 seconds into the video clip) you can see the explosion for a frame or two. The cut up and exploded DeLorean's body panels were actually reassembled at the Planet Hollywood Honolulu restaurant and can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pjNTZvtpEQ) so you can see how the car was sliced up.

Train-car collisions definitely cause some devastating damage, but in real life you can expect more crumpling and crushing than exploding into a million pieces.